# Fixing rlang access denied

Tags: r, rlang

Can't seem to find a viable solution getting rlang to install after updating rstudio.
I tried using --no lock on builder tools https://work.sparktseung.com/pages/2021-09-06-R-build-package-permission/
Also tried uninstalling it and reinstalling w/ remove.packages this hasn't worked for me either after restarting.

```
> library(rlang)
Error in library(rlang) : there is no package called ‘rlang’
> remove.packages("rlang")
Removing package from ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘rlang’
Restarting R session...
> library(rlang)
Error in library(rlang) : there is no package called ‘rlang’
```

Here's the error when trying to install via url

```
Warning in file.rename(instdir, final_instdir) :
  cannot rename file 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/00LOCK-rlang/00new/rlang' to 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rlang', reason 'Access is denied'
ERROR:    moving to final location failed
* removing 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rlang'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8sB5rS/downloaded_packages/rlang_1.0.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Install Line

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_1.0.5.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
```

Session Info

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0 tools_4.2.0
```

Really need to run some scripts, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Close R/Rstudio, go to `C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/` via windows explorer, and delete the rlang folder. Than reopen R and run `install.packages("rlang")`

Comment: I ran into the same error. I tried removing the package "rlang" and reinstalling a newer version, but nothing helped. In the end, it turned out that I had used the outdated version of R and could not run the script without errors until I ran updateR() in R (updating the version of R to the latest one).